# Ubuntu One OpenID Failure

Tags: ubuntu-one, software-center

```
Failure to login to one.ubuntu.com as well as Ubuntu Software Center from the desktop.

Attempting to login to one.ubuntu.com results in the following error: "Authentication failed: OpenID authentication failed: Bad signature".

Attempting to make a purchase from Ubuntu Software Center (Steam), the screen switches to "Connecting to Payment Service..." followed by an error popup claiming: "Sorry, something went wrong. Your payment has been cancelled.".
```

This is from Ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um, yeah, sorry about this - there is indeed a problem on the server side involving non-ASCII characters and the OpenID library we're using, since we rolled out a new feature this week.  The fix is ready and I expect it will be rolled out pretty quickly, given the severity.  In the meantime, it can be worked around by going to login.ubuntu.com and ensuring that your full name doesn't contain any non-ASCII characters.

To track this bug, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/canonical-identity-provider/+bug/1181229